# unexpected StringCases behaviour inside function module

Tags: functions, replacement, scoping

First, Let use see

```
a = {"wx", "wy", "wz"};
AssociationThread[Flatten[StringCases[a, "w" ~~ d_ :> d]] -> a]
```

gives

```
<|"x" -> "wx", "y" -> "wy", "z" -> "wz"|>
```

Now comes the weird thing. Define

```
ClearAll[test];
test[] := Module[{a},
  a = {"wx", "wy", "wz"};
  AssociationThread[Flatten[StringCases[a, "w" ~~ d_ :> d]] -> a]
  ]
```

and run `test[]`, gives

```
<|d -> "wz"|>
```

Why?

If you look at the `test[]//Trace`, you will find `"w" ~~ d$_ :> d` appears. What is `d$_`?

If we define

```
ClearAll[test];
test[] := Module[{},
  a = {"wx", "wy", "wz"};
  AssociationThread[Flatten[StringCases[a, "w" ~~ d_ :> d]] -> a]
  ]
```

or

```
ClearAll[test];
test[] := Module[{a,dList},
  a = {"wx", "wy", "wz"};
  dList = Flatten[StringCases[a, "w" ~~ d_ :> d]];
  AssociationThread[dList -> a]
  ]
```

then `test[]` gives correct answer.

Can someone explain the above behaviour? How could Module `a` variable affect the rule replacement of `d`?

Comment: If you simplify to `Flatten[StringCases[a,"w"~~d_:>d]]->a` inside the module you get `{d,d,d}->{"wx","wy","wz"}`. It looks like what's happening is something is broken when module isolates `d`. I don't know why it's isolating `d`, seems to be due to the `->a`. Normally `a$123` is used to create a unique version of scoped variables in things like `Module`. Because `d_` becomes `d$_` the rule is replacing with the actual symbol `d` and not the matched `d$`. The association is then  merging the degenerate values for the key `d`. This looks like a bug to me, I'd report it.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Thanks for reply. You're right. `AssociationThread` is irrelavent

Answer (score 8):

This is a long-standing scoping issue. While we do not have a full resolution, often these can be addressed by a non-default system option setting.

```
SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];

test[] := Module[{a},
  a = {"wx", "wy", "wz"};
  AssociationThread[Flatten[StringCases[a, "w" ~~ d_ :> d]] -> a]]

In[641]:= test[]

(* Out[641]= <|"x" -> "wx", "y" -> "wy", "z" -> "wz"|> *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. It indeed works. But I am wondering what bad side effects can we get if we always set `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];`. If for some reason we can not always set StrictLexicalScoping, what is the rule of thumb to avoid these unexpected behaviour(You know it is really a headache to track down such innocent "bug"s)?

Comment: I do not know offhand what issues will arise from that setting. We have had seen bad interaction between it and display of `Dataset`, seemingly from an incessant retriggering of formatting. Offhand I do not know if that remains problematic though.

Comment: Thank you for valuable information